# Bar chart xAxis grid lines are in centre instead besides

Tags: ios, swift, charts, bar-chart, ios-charts

I spent more than half of my day on it and unable to figure out solution

drawing bar chart using [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) pod facing two problems

1. Wanna Corner radius bars as mentioned in required Image
2. wanna bars besides the grid line as in below image

**Required**
[image: required output]

My output is something like this

**Output**

[image: Wrong Out put]

Comment: search 'Round bar' in Chart issues list in github, there are many discussion.

Comment: greate and what's about xaxis grid line?

Comment: you can add `ChartLimitLine` for every `x` in `xAxis`, and set `xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false`

Comment: kun wang 
xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false. 

this line of cord just hiding x-axis grid lines. in my case I have to enabled them at besides as shown in requirement.jpeg

Comment: I write a simple [demo](https://github.com/wzio/ChartDemo)

Comment: thanks you solved my problem and add your solution in answer instead of comment because bounty reward  is yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two method

1. override `XAxisRender` to make offset x grid line. override `BarChartRenderer` to add round corner
2. use `ChartLimitLine` instead of x grid line. and fork [Chart](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) and change `BarChartRenderer`  to implement round corner

this is my [demo](https://github.com/wzio/ChartDemo) implemented all you want with method 2